# Concavity of log likelihood for hidden markov models

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, markov-chain

Could you give me a good link where the concept of concavity of the log likelihood related to hidden markov model EM algorithm is clarified? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't a hidden markov model a very general class of models?  Meaning that concavity can only be obtained for a certain class of models?  I think you need to add more information about which particular HMM you are taking about.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, asking about why the EM algorithm works for HMM, i.e., via an application of Jensen's inequality and what role concavity plays in the proof?

Comment: @cardinal♦ yes exactly